# What is the purpose of this sidecar-injector-configmap.yaml file？and how to config the IPRanges for network control?

Tags: istio

Source: istio/templates/sidecar-injector-configmap.yaml ，

What is the purpose of this sidecar-injector-configmap.yaml file？
Can I configure the part related to accessing the external network in this file?

please focus on how to add IP ranges into below sections?

```
[[ if (isset .ObjectMeta.Annotations "traffic.sidecar.istio.io/includeOutboundIPRanges") -]] 
     - "[[ index .ObjectMeta.Annotations "traffic.sidecar.istio.io/includeOutboundIPRanges" ]]" 
     [[ else -]] 
     - "*" 
     [[ end -]] 
     - "-x" 
     [[ if (isset .ObjectMeta.Annotations "traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeOutboundIPRanges") -]] 
     - "[[ index .ObjectMeta.Annotations "traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeOutboundIPRanges" ]]" 
     [[ else -]] 
     - "" 
     [[ end -]] 
     - "-b" 
     [[ if (isset .ObjectMeta.Annotations "traffic.sidecar.istio.io/includeInboundPorts") -]] 
     - "[[ index .ObjectMeta.Annotations "traffic.sidecar.istio.io/includeInboundPorts" ]]"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not that experienced with Istio, but it seems like you are not looking into right direction. Purpose of `sidecar-injector-configmap` is:

> Manual and automatic injection both use the configuration from the
>   istio-sidecar-injector and istio ConfigMaps in the istio-system
>   namespace. Manual injection can also optionally load configuration
>   from local files.

You can find more information about the sidecar injector [here](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/sidecar-injection/#injection).

> By default, Istio-enabled services are unable to access URLs outside
>   of the cluster because the pod uses iptables to transparently redirect
>   all outbound traffic to the sidecar proxy, which only handles
>   intra-cluster destinations.

From what I was able to find the IP ranges should be configured in Ingress or Egress depending what exactly you want to do. You can find more about configuring network access in this sections - [Ingress](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/), [Egress](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/).